# Export data from Sharepoint to excel

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel, export

I have a little trouble with export data from SharePoint 2010 and Excel, i need get data from a SharePoint list, to do a sum of certain fields that are in the list.

I prove the Power Query option for that, but is not working, because problems of credentials

If there is another method to do that, please, tell me.

PD: The export to excel methods doesn't work in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would be to use powershell. Here's a quick and dirty example using the server-side snapin:

```
$web =  get-spweb "myweb url"
$list = $web.Lists["MyListName"]
$listData.GetItems().GetDataTable()
$listData | export-csv -Path "myfile.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

You could also use CSOM if you don't have server-side access but it's a little more complex (not that bad).

Comment: This method replaces the whole file? or add rows in the case?
Because, i need the 2nd case, the process must be automatic

And, Can I do this method but with a View of a List?

Comment: If you add the -append flag to the export-csv command, it will add to the file rather than overwrite. The method listed here will export all fields from the list (including hidden ones). If you'd like to be more selective, you could add a Select command to the chain. E.G. $listData | Select FieldTitle1, FieldTitle2 | export-csv -path "myfile.csv" -notypeInformation -append

Answer (score 0):

Export SharePoint list items to CSV using PowerShell for your reference:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/04/export-sharepoint-list-items-to-csv-using-powershell.html